# How can I get a formula to run if there is data in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have created a formula that compiles data and returns a "Pass" or "Fail" in cell A.  However, I do not want it to populate anything unless that line is filled in.  The formula in Cell A: is autofilled for 5000 lines.  I only want it to populate once the information is in the other cells.

=IFERROR(IF(G3="",""),IF(AND(AE3+AF3>=65,AT3="PASS",BA3="PASS"),"PASS","FAIL")).  This leaves cell A blank, but once I add data, it Says False, not "PASS" or "FAIL".

I am new to formulas and such and would really appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Misplaced parentheses:

```
=IFERROR(IF(G3="","",IF(AND(AE3+AF3>=65,AT3="PASS",BA3="PASS"),"PASS","FAIL")),"")
```

Comment: You are the best!!!!  It worked.  Thank you so much :)

Comment: @FawnMarieGallipeau  You are quite welcome !